# Use string when indexing object

Tags: python

If I have something like

```
class test:
  val = False

thing = test()
thing1 = test()

a = input() # In this case a would be "thing"
a.val = True
```

How could I get my code to read `a` as `thing` when setting the value of `a.val`?

Comment: Note, you aren't indexing any object in your code.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best practice security-wise, but you can use eval:

`a = eval(input())`

Also to set an instance attribute you need to define your class as follows:

`class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = False`